# How to add fileds dynamically using javascript with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I got the code add fields dynamically here [Add fields dynamically - link](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-form-fields-add-amp-remove-bs3)

when I try use this code insight my form class `<form class="form-horizontal"  action="create.php"  method="post">`  it won't work but when put this filed out from form class it will work I know have to changes in **java script** but I'm new to **JS** so please help me the changes

this my form:

```
<body>
  <form class="form-horizontal"  action="create.php"  method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="des" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To Address</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="controls"> 
          <form role="form" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="entry input-group ">
              <input class="form-control"name="fields[]"type="text"     placeholder="To....." />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-add"type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> </button> </span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save"   id="search"/>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

myscript :

```
<script>
$(function()
{
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

        newEntry.find('input').val('');
        controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
            .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
            .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
            .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
    }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
    {
        $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: please create a jsfiddle with your code so you can get help.

Comment: You have form inside form, that's not legal. Try to remove that, because nowadays browsers automatically delete form and your html changes in frontend!

Comment: @Michael do u have any solution for this...? javascript function work ?

Comment: @HamelRaj remove inside `<form>` and remove class from div - controls, and add class `controls` to `<body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i did a mistake to add form insight form the easy way to add multiple fields :

```
<label for="des" class=" control-label">Description</label>
         <div class="multi-field-wrapper ">
           <div class="multi-fields">
             <div class="multi-field">
             <div class="col-sm-8">
               <input id="des" type="text" class="form-control" name="descrip[]"></div>
               <span class="remove-field">
                 <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></span>
             </div>
             </div>
         <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
        </div>
```

script funtion :

```
 $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
    $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
        $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
    });
    $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
        if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
            $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in your HTML markup, adding a form inside another form, and i had a look at your reference, you would see you did make a mistake.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="control-group" id="fields">
        <label class="control-label" for="field1">Nice Multiple Form Fields</label>
        <div class="controls"> 
            <form role="form" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="entry input-group col-xs-3">
                    <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        <br>
        <small>Press <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus gs"></span> to add another form field :)</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if you wanted to add your POST method, you would add it into the form tag there, and not create a new one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want use this code insight my form when i use this code insight my form it wont work ??????

Comment: You can't add a form inside a form, if you submit, it doesn't work. Here a plunkr to test, i have edited your code [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/pZrQ2gb5zOq7VTxictA6?p=preview)

Comment: i know if i put that filed out sight of my form it will work but i want know how to use insight my form don't b .........